# Copy and paste a stamp with populated form fields without the pop-up box prompting me to complete the filled fields everytime in adobe?

Tags: javascript, adobe, pdfstamper, stamp

I created a custom Adobe stamp with form fields and included a Javascript so that when it's first applied, a prompt appears that asks 2 questions and then auto populates the date.

All of this works great but I then need to copy and paste the stamp to all pages, but it prompts me to reanswer those questions. In some cases these are hundreds of pages. I'm not familiar enough to understand how to modify the script, so I'd like to ask the community for some assistance in rewriting it.

Here is the code below. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT
// SEE GLOBAL JAVASCRIPT SECTION FOR CUSTOMIZATION

if ((event.source.forReal)&&(event.source.stampName == "#MDPNVOGWHXAIUOPZ")) {

    this.getField("formfield1").value = app.response("question1:");

    this.getField("formfield2").value = app.response("Enter queation2:");

    this.getField("Date").value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", new Date());

}
```